# relocation R_X86_64_32 against symbol `G8' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE

Tags: linker, llvm, linker-errors, llvm-ir

I'm trying to compile lambda-expressions from scheme to llvm-ir and am having trouble with position independet code.

source:

```
(lambda (x) (display x))
```

target:

```
bunch of declares...
define %SObj* @G7() {
entry:
  %calltmp = call %SObj* @closure_create(i64 ptrtoint (%SObj* (%SObj*)* @G8 to i64), %SObj* null)
  ret %SObj* %calltmp
}

define %SObj* @G8(%SObj* %G6) {
entry:
  %calltmp = call %SObj* @display(%SObj* %G6)
  ret %SObj* %calltmp
}

define i32 @main(i32 %0, i8** %1) {
entry:
  %calltmp = call %SObj* @G7()
  %calltmp1 = call %SObj* @display(%SObj* %calltmp)
  ret i32 0
}
```

compiling this with:

```
llc code.ll && clang code.s -L/usr/lib -lgc -lSRuntime -o code -v
```

where code.ll is the printed ll-ir module gives me the error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/code-1c0b5f.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against symbol `G8' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
```

Reading up on PIE doesn't quite help me solve my issue. Can someone explain me, why the ptrtoint cast in G7 causes the code to be non-PIC and how one would then implement such behaviour?

EDIT: Issue was solved by adding --relocation-model=pic to the llc call, which compiles the module

Comment: Have you recompiles with the `fPIE` flag as the error message suggests?

Comment: Thanks!  Not so easy to find, since --relocation-model is not mentionned in llc man page, only in lli's (which in cited in the 'see also' section of llc's).

Comment: I have the same error, I am new in C/C++. Where can I get info about how to use the fPIE flag?